# How can I differentiate unordered lists in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I'm still fumbling through this design and am having trouble with un-ordered lists (ul).  I am attempting to set up a horizontal scrolling carousel on my page and needed the images to line up.  I imput the following into CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

It did the trick, the images are inline now, however this also affected the navigation bar which affected some javascript I had running.

How can I make the image list separate from the navigation list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't target generic UL/LI - target specific element either by class or by ID

Comment: why don't you use more specific css element? example #navi ul instead of ul

Comment: If you want you could just do Ul:nth-last-child > li { display: inline-block}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, consider 2 ULs:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>    
</ul>    

<ul id="pic">
    <li>Pic 1</li>
    <li>Pic 2</li>
    <li>Pic 3</li>    
</ul>
```

If you use your original CSS - it will affect both items, because they're both UL. But if you target specic "pic" element like this:

```
#pic {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#pic li {
  display: inline;
}
```

this will affect only second element.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3vRYA/**

Comment: this worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.  now to figure out how to get the images to move up.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Give them a class, either the li itself or the enclosing ul/ol:

```
.MyListType1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


<ul class="MyListType1">
```

You can use id where you only have one of them on the page `<ul id="MainNav">` or class where you have several `<ul class="MiniLinks">` and then refer to them with either a hash or a dot. For id `#MainNav {}`. For class `.MiniLinks {}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

*specifically you can use it as well and now no longer affects or other*

```
<ul id="ul">
     <li class="li">Pic 1</li>   
</ul> 


    #ul, #ul > .li {
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Using element names as class and id names is just confusing

Comment: is an example :) anyway is something used and does not affect the code

Answer (score 0):

ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; 
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height: 100px; /*optional*/
    width: 100px; /*optional*/
}